# How should I maintain my conf when upgrading a hombrew package?

Tags: macos, upgrade, homebrew

I have freeswitch installed via homebrew. It is not a well designed package and keeps its conf and data in the package dir, so when upgrading you lose your setup by default. I'm just wondering what people have done to move their configs forward in such situations.

I'm not sure which files have changes in them, and while I can easily backup the existing conf, mod, and sounds dirs; I'm not keen on simply overwriting the new files completely as things may have changed that I shouldn't be clobbering.

I was thinking a recursive diff against the new dir might be a start but I'm not sure that's the best way to approach the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just recently came across a cool utility that may help called [Mackup](https://github.com/lra/mackup). This gem will backup a slew of your config files for many apps but you can even create custom config files so that it will backup any file you want. You can backup to a cloud service, local file system or a git repo. And it already supports over 250 app configs.

And you can install it from Homebrew or pip. Hope this helps.